# Java performance pooling vs blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am considering two approaches for sending some kind of messages over network.

1) There is a LoadBalancer with internal cache which has reference to Channels. Each channel has inner thread(callable) which has implementation for sending the messages and public interface on which it accepts sendMessage requests.

Channel offers method to LoadBalancer on which it can do non-blocking query weather it is available to send another message.

To summarize: there is one Thread for LoadBalancer which continuously pools list of channels with something along the lines isChannelReady() and sends another message when channel is ready.

```
public class SomeLoadBalancingStrategy implements LoadBalancer {
private List<Channel> channels = ChannelFactory.getChannels(//parameters here)

// read from some queue
while(there are messages) {

foreach (channel) {

// non blocking query
if(channel.isReady()) {

       channel.sendMessage(message)
    }
  }
}
```

2) Each channel object consits of runnable thread which wraps inner callable responsible for sending messages. Channels are blocked on some concurrent queue waiting for new messages. When message is added to queue, channel runnable picks it up and passes to callable. This runnable is blocked waiting for result. Once result of callable is available, thread wrapping it will pick up next message from queue, perhaps via LoadBalancer interface.

So, to summarize: there are two threads per channel, one which is callable and sends message and second one waiting for that result so it can pick up next request. In this scenario, there is no separate LoadBalancer thread dispatching messages to channels.

Some notes:

- Channels use synchronous communication with endpoint
- Please consider my explanation of solutions just as a template for base ideas     that i would like to discuss
- There will be small number of channels, 5 at most

Would second approach always be better performance wise ? Are there conditions under which first option would be better ? Hardware, OS, anything ?
If channels were asynchronous, would it make difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution number one seem to have a constant polling in the load balancer asking each channel whether it is ready.

That is going to add unnecessary CPU consumption. I would change the 1) to avoid that by keeping a blocking queue of "ready" channels. The Load balancer would pull a ready channel from the queue and the channels would add themselves to the queue when they become ready for another request.

In 2) Don't see why you need two threads per channel unless is somehow imposed by the implementation of the operation dispenser (the Callable API?).

IMO both options seem quite equivalent in performance, I don't see why one would do much better than the other; that said,  1) may guarantee that all channels are equally used in a round-robin phasion whereas in 2) if there is low message traffic there is the possibility that the same channel is always doing the work depending on how the VM manages the collection of Java threads waiting for a new item in the request message queue.

Comment: Yep thinking about it, there is no need to have two threads per channel in second option. I like your suggestion of blocking queue of channels to which channels attach themselves. This is also very convenient if one of the channels goes down temporary. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Assuming i use blocking queue of channels, how would i break out of blocking on such queue, if i wanted to do so? Lets say that i want do so every so often :) I guess adding (and reading) some special element which indicates there are no more messages ?

Comment: @user3360241 Not sure what you mean. I guess you are talking about option 1. Why wouldn't you want the load-balancer to be blocked if there is no more channels available (and until some become available)? Can you be more specific? Otherwise it sounds like you are reverting to the CPU intensive polling constantly asking until the ready channel queue is not empty and I think that that is kind of pointless if not a waste of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

> Would second approach always be better performance wise ?

Impossible to say.  The best option is to test both approaches.  Usually the simplest solution is best and adding queue in front of queue isn't always useful (The TCP stream is a queue of bytes)

> Are there conditions under which first option would be better ?

Dedicated threads are often easier to reason about and can perform better.  This will work better when you have a small number of threads.

> If channels were asynchronous, would it make difference ?

Yes, but it not possible to say if it better, but it will be more complicated.

I suggest you have a look at [netty](http://netty.io/), if not to use it, but to learn from the approach it uses.

Comment: "Could you please comment on: Dedicated threads are often easier to reason about and can perform better.                                                          This will work better when you have a small number of threads." There is in both cases dedicated thread per channel. First option, one for LoadBalancer and 1 per channel. Second option, two per channel and 0 for LoadBalancer.

Comment: The time it takes to pass data between the reading thread, the processing thread and the passing back to the writing thread is reduced if you the reading thread is the processing thread, and optionally the same thread can also the writing thread.

Comment: @user3360241 why not just have one thread per channel and only add threads if you know you need it?

Comment: This is very good question. There is no need to have two threads per channel in second option. Thank you for your answer and I would accept it but Valetino added additional improvement to first option, with blocking queue of channels and i haven't thought of that.   +1 on answer